# How to retrieve status for async call to an REST API performing a task

Tags: java

I have some java code which calls an asynchronous REST API to finish a task that takes a while to complete, this call returns a task ID. We would need to use the task ID and trigger another REST call to retrieve the task completion status. Please suggest the best mechanism to poll the status using java. Can I use quartz job to achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

I think introducing Quartz for just this will be an overkill. Have a look at [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).